# ruby run parallel tasks in background and return results without displaying stdout?

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, chef-infra, knife

I am working on a chef knife bootstrap script and am trying to make it work on windows or POSIX based systems. In it I'm trying to query chef-server for roles and environments. On windows the queries can take up to 30 seconds, so I'm trying to run them in parallel and in the background and store the values to be called upon later as I ask the user for other input and then eventually to pick a role and environment returned from the queries. For the life of me I can not figure out how to get queries to run in the background without pause the main program.

Here is what I have so far:

```
chef_role = `knife search role '*:*' -i`.split.map { |i| { name: i } }.sort_by! { |n| n[:name] }
chef_env = `knife search environment '*' -i`.split.map { |i| { name: i } }.sort_by! { |n| n[:name] }
# Parallel fetch chef resources
knife_search = [chef_role, chef_env]
par = []
i = 0
knife_search.each do |search|
  par[i] = Thread.new do
    search
  end
  i += 1
end
par.each(&:join)
puts "Test1 = #{chef_role.inspect} | Test2 = #{chef_env.inspect}"
```

Comment: The backtick method waits for output, it blocks. You need a non-blocking approach like [`popen3`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Open3.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be using one of the APIs like chef-api for Ruby or PyChef for Python.